# Error occurred while trying to connect to db in aws

Tags: spring, oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I deployed war file to aws which is spring project. and I installed oracle rds on aws. When I try to connect to oracle rds on aws from my local computer with root-context.xml. It worked. It can connect to oracle rds on aws from my local computer with my spring project. But when I try to run spring war file on aws. http://ip address:8080 it gives me an error message. Would you please help me with this?
I have been struggling with this for three days...any help would be appreciated.

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

here is the root-context.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy"></property>

        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:log4jdbc:oracle:thin:@database ip address on aws:1521:orcl" />
        <property name="username" value="id" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>
```

aws security inbound setting:

```
http tcp 80 0.0.0.0/0
custom tcp rule 8080 0.0.0.0/0
custom tcp rule 8080 ::/0
[database setting][1]

[security group][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/869s0.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqaeU.png
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying and trying - created another RDS DB, copying existing one, created another VPC to try it out there are few things that need to be considered (obviously, they are all documented, but it's not an easy task to find all the information, since - at least in my case - it wasn't documented in one place:

1. If you want your DB instance in the VPC to be publicly accessible, you must enable the VPC attributes DNS hostnames and DNS resolution (existing VPC can be changed too).
2. Check the VPC security group and enable the DB access port (in case of the standard MS SQL deployment - 1433) - since starting the 2013, VPC security groups have replaced the RDS security group.
3. Check thoroughly the RDS DB information for Security Groups, port and other info that can be misidentified.
4. Somehow not obvious (at least for me at first), but when using SQL Management Studio to access the RDS DB - do not use the ":1433" or other port identifier at the end of DB instance name.
5. If nothing of the above works, ask the question here and keep googling... :)

Most of the info found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSVPC.html

Comment: Thank you for your help! I reedit my question for the pics about setting. would you please look at them and see if anything is wrong. Thank you

Comment: I can connect to oracle rds on aws with root-context.xml setting on my local computer so that means. Setting on my root-context.xml is correct, right?